# What is the right invariant $\sigma$-algebra for the Birkhoff ergodic theorem?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, ergodic-theory, stochastic-analysis

I have been reading stuff about ergodic theory, and I have encountered two versions of the involved "invariant sigma field". let the underlying probability space be $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, and let's consider a measure preserving transformation $T:\Omega \rightarrow \Omega$). then the two definitions of the $T$-invariant sets are:

1) $\mathcal{I}_1:=\{A \in \mathcal{F} \mid T^{-1}A=A\}$;

2) $\mathcal{I}_2:=\{A \in \mathcal{F} \mid P(T^{-1}A \Delta A) = 0\}$;

obviously, $\mathcal{I}_1\subseteq\mathcal{I}_2$. but I don't think that $\mathcal{I}_2\subseteq\mathcal{I}_1$ holds as well. 2hat is the relationship between the two (is the larger one the completion of the smaller one?)?

But here is the prime question: which one is the right "conditioning" sigma field for the limit in Birkhoff's ergodic theorem? Are the conditional expectations versions of each other? If yes, how would you show that?

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal N$ denote the subsets $N$ of $\Omega$ for $N\in \mathcal F$   and $\mu(N)=0$.

We actually have (thanks Harry for fixing that) $\mathcal I_2=\sigma(\mathcal I_1,\mathcal N)$.

Indeed, if $B\in\mathcal I_2$, then $\mu(B\Delta T^{-1}B)=0$. We define $C:=\bigcap_{N\geqslant 0}\bigcup_{n\geqslant N}T^{-n}B$. Then $\mu(C\Delta B)=0 $ and $C\in\mathcal I_1$. We thus take $N:=C\Delta B$ and observe that $$B = C \setminus (C \cap N) \cup ( B \cap N) \in \sigma(\{\mathcal{I}_1, \mathcal{N}\}).$$

Let us prove that $\mu(C\Delta B)=0 $. From the fact that $\mu(B\Delta T^{-n}B)=0$ for each $n$, and defining $C_N:=\bigcup_{n\geqslant N}T^{-n}B$, we get $\mu(B\Delta C_N)=0$ for each $N$. Now notice that $C_N\downarrow C$.

Comment: many thanks for your help, I really like your answer. I just cannot verify that $\mu(C\Delta B)=0$ - I'm sorry to bother you with this, but I am just not able to come up with a formal argument. maybe you can provide a few more details for that step? many thanks!

Comment: @s_2 See edit. It indeed deserved more details.

Comment: ok, got it - again, many thanks for your help!!!

Comment: New to this thread. Two questions. One, don't you mean $\mathcal I_2=\{S\Delta N, S\in\mathcal I_1,N\in\mathcal N\}$ ? Second, the proof seems to work also with $C:=\bigcup_{N\geqslant 0}\bigcap_{n\geqslant N}T^{-n}B$, am I right?

Comment: Edit to my first question, don't you mean $\mathcal I_2=\{S' | S\in\mathcal I_1, S\Delta S' \in\mathcal N\}$ ?

Comment: If the goal is to show that $B = S \cup N$ where $S \in \mathcal{I}_1$ and $N = C \triangle B$, what do you take for $S$? Setting $S:=C$ does not seem to work out, since $C \cup N = C \cup C \triangle B = C \cup B$.

Comment: Upon further thought, it seems that $\mathcal{I}_2 = \sigma(\{\mathcal{I}_1, \mathcal{N}\})$. Clearly, $\mathcal{I}_1 \subset \mathcal{I}_2, \mathcal{N} \subset \mathcal{I}_2$. For any $B \in \mathcal{I}_2$ one can consider $C \in \mathcal{I}_1$ as above, set $N := B \triangle C$ and observe that $B = C \setminus (C \cap N) \cup ( B \cap N) \in \sigma(\{\mathcal{I}_1, \mathcal{N}\})$.

Comment: @Harry Yes, it seems to be the completion of $\mathcal I_1$.

Comment: I realized that you had assumed that $\mathcal{N}$ includes all subsets of null sets in $\mathcal{F}$. Shouldn't one actually let $\mathcal{N}$ be the class of all the measurable null sets in $\mathcal{F}$? This is in fact necessary for the inclusion $\mathcal{N} \subset \mathcal{I}_2$.

Comment: @Harry Good point, indeed, the previous version of $\mathcal N$ was the right one.